# Right panel grows with left panel, eventhough not nested

Tags: html, css

I have a weird situation. I have two panels on my page. A sidemenu and a main content area.

In that main content area i have a `div` and inside that `div` i float two other `divs`. One to the left and the other to the right. I then `clear` both div at the end, but then the container `div` is as high as my side menu. But they are not nested, so i don't see why and how this is happening...

**Here is a demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/9duUt/1/

If you remove the two foating DIVs and the DIV that clears the float, then you'll see that the container div has its normal size.

Why is this happening when i float the divs?

---

## The source code from that fiddle

```
<div class="sidemenu">
    aaa<br />aaa<br />aaa<br />aaa<br />aaa<br />aaa<br />aaa<br />
    aaa<br />aaa<br />aaa<br />aaa<br />aaa<br />aaa<br />aaa<br />
</div>

<div class="main-content">
    <div class="top-bar">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th large"></span> Test</h1>
            <h5>Sub title</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
        CHARTS
        </div>
        <div class="fc"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.main-content {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FCFCFC 0%, #E2E2E2 18%, #EAEAEA 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.top-bar {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.pull-left {
    float: left !important;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right !important;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
}

.fc {
    clear: both;
}

.sidemenu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #11161A;
    float: left;
    min-width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Not sure but you are looking for a fix or explanation why is this happening ?

Comment: http://complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `.fc` clear class is also clearing your sidebar which also happens to be floated left - despite your `.sidebar` not being nested within `.main-content` (as that is how the [`clear`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control) property works) - Removing the `.fc` mark-up and applying `overflow: hidden;` to `.top-bar` (which provides a new [Block Formatting Context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) for its floated descendants) will give you the behaviour you probably expected. You also get rid of unnecessary mark-up.

```
.top-bar {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9duUt/4/

---

The definition of the `both` value from the [2.1 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html):

> **Both**
>
> Requires that the top border edge of the box be below the bottom outer edge of any right-floating and left-floating boxes that resulted from **elements earlier in the source document**.

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like your main-content could just be floated left, with out the margin, to fix this up. Like so.

```
.main-content {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FCFCFC 0%, #E2E2E2 18%, #EAEAEA 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    float: left;
  }
```

You could just give it a specific width to fix things up.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the problem is in *fc* class. It looks like it is clearing the float of the *sidemenu* and it goes below it in height. That's why your *main-content* is increased. Anyway, I think that you should keep the clearing because this could mess the things a lot in the future. Just add *float: left;* to *main-content* and remove *margin-left*. The other problem you have to fix after that is the width of *main-content*. You should put some static value I guess. Here is your jsfiddle forked with my changes: http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/pxgrt/2/

```
.main-content {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FCFCFC 0%, #E2E2E2 18%, #EAEAEA 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```